# C++ video handling

Tags: c++, video-processing

What is the **easiest** method for reading in the raw data (raw RGB image data for each frame) from a video file, in C++.

I really would appreciate some good detailed responses, or helpful links. I intend to manipulate the data using inline assembly.

I am using microsoft visual C++ 2010 express.

Comment: Could you define handling? Do you want to render/filter/compress? And where does your video stream come from?

Comment: I need the image data (char*) for each frame. The stream will come from a file (or maybe a webcam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the frame, [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) is a good tool. [Here](http://nashruddin.com/How_to_Play_AVI_Files_with_OpenCV) you have a pointer to read video.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DirectShow for this purpose. There are many add-ons available to help you render most of the video formats. It also supports rendering images from webcams AFAIK. The other alternative would be to use MediaFoundation SDK that comes with Windows SDK 7.0. MediaFoundation SDK will supersede DirectShow in future.